# Convert CSV to RDF and cast string to date type using TARQL

Tags: xsd, sparql

Let's say that I have the following csv file with a date column - [full example here](https://github.com/erikaduan/sparql_with_hobbits/blob/main/data/raw_data/farming.csv).

| Date | Farmer | Product | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04-09-2021 | Bolger | pumpkin | 29 |
| 04-09-2021 | Bolger | tomato | 62 |

How do I write a TARQL script which can successfully include `Date` and convert `Date` into a RDF recognized date/dateTime format? I tried the following code and it failed to include `Date` in the generated RDF TURTLE file.

```
PREFIX ex: <http://www.hobbiton.com/schema>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

CONSTRUCT {
  ?product_iri ex:product ?Product ; 
  ex:farmer ?Farmer ;
  ex:date ?date ;
  ex:count ?count . 
}
FROM <file:farming.csv>
WHERE { 
  BIND(REPLACE(STR(?Product),"[ ]","_") AS ?product)
  BIND (IRI(CONCAT('http://www.hobbiton.com/schema/product#', ?product)) AS ?product_iri) 
  BIND (xsd:integer(?Count) AS ?count)
  BIND (xsd:dateTime(?Date) AS ?date)
}
```

Unexpected result

```
@base          <file:///C:/Users/Erika/OneDrive/Desktop/git_repos/sparql_with_hobbits/scripts/convert_farming_csv_unstructured.rq> .
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix ex:  <http://www.hobbiton.com/schema> .
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://www.hobbiton.com/schema/product#pumpkin>
        ex:product  "pumpkin" ;
        ex:farmer   "Bolger" ;
        ex:count    29 .

<http://www.hobbiton.com/schema/product#tomato>
        ex:product  "tomato" ;
        ex:farmer   "Bolger" ;
        ex:count    62 .
```

I assume `count` has been cast into an integer type but `date` has disappeared altogether from the resulting TURTLE `.rq` file.

Comment: `4/09/2021` is not a valid lexical form of `xsd:date`, that would be `04/09/2021`

Comment: Edit: I've just read your comment again. Thanks, I'll try converting the raw date format manually and test `xsd:dateTime(?Date)`.

Comment: can you try `BIND (strdt(?Date, xsd:date) AS ?date)` please?

Comment: Odd. The CSV appears to have a valid form of `xsd:date` [here](https://github.com/erikaduan/sparql_with_hobbits/blob/main/data/raw_data/farming.csv) and the script now has `BIND (strdt(?Date, xsd:date) AS ?date)` [here](https://github.com/erikaduan/sparql_with_hobbits/blob/main/scripts/convert_farming_csv_unstructured.rq). But `date` still fails to show up in the RDF file format. I wonder if there's something wrong with how I'm calling `data` using TARQL itself? I might test a few other different column types.

Comment: I should say that my command line code is `tarql --write-base convert_farming_csv_unstructured.rq ..\data\raw_data\farming.csv`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, XML date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: your header contains an illegal character before `Dates` - once you deleted that `BIND (strdt(?Dates, xsd:date) AS ?date)` works as expected

Comment: I couldn't find the illegal character you referred to but I played around with different columns and somehow the expected RDF is produced if I leave the first column in the csv blank. `BIND (strdt(?Dates, xsd:date) AS ?date)` also worked very nicely thanks. [Expected RDF finally produced](https://github.com/erikaduan/sparql_with_hobbits/blob/main/data/clean_data/farming_unstructured.rdf).